# Apache FOP - how to find which data will be printed on which page

Tags: java, apache, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to generate PDF from XSLT in my retail project and then print the PDF. A new requirement has come to print the running total in the footer of every page of receipt.

I am not sure how to achieve this because until unless we transform XSL to PDF, we don't know on which page it will be printed or is there anything I am not aware of?

Example:

PDF Page 1:

Item 1     10

Item 2     20

### Total      30

Page 2:

Item 3    20

Item 4    10

### Total     60

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some google and finally found the solution that it can be done in XSLT itself.

Refer http://www.java4less.com/apache/fop.php?info=xslfosubtotals

Adding this answer just if someone else needs it.